# Strange chrome media queries behaviour

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, media-queries

I have a layout that breaks at 500px using floats and inline-blocks to shift elements. But chrome(40) does not render them correctly after breaking from smaller to larger size.

Here's the initial mobile layout
[image: initial]

Expected layout on resize
[image: expected]

Incorrect result
[image: incorrect result]

The div containing edit/delete buttons is displayed inline-block and floated right, but does not stack along the 'tags'.

```
div.link-div div.edit-delete {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    background-color: #3498db;
}
```

Complete CSS [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abhimanyuPathania/o3z26x2r/1/).

My break point is between mobile rotations so the browser will resize. This works fine for FF, IE. Is something wrong in CSS? Please give some workaround.

Comment: Interestingly, if you load the page in a viewport >500px wide, it lays out as expected. Resizing to hit the breakpoint, then enlarging again, triggers the error.

Comment: @Palpatim Yes. In the code above you just have to refresh when you hit break-point while enlarging. But a poor work-around is already there in my code. If you look at the date span in div.content it renders just fine :). It's the exact opposite of what I did with edit/control buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a way to solve the problem would be adding a "float: left;" to the anchor Tags, to make sure it doesn't occur. You can wrap them in a *div* and 'float' that *div* left in opposition to the "edit-delete" *div*.

Here is your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kxvqqrhx/) edited. I created a class to the *div* called "tags-div", which, on *MediaQuery* is set to "float:left;" on screen sizes bigger than 500px.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 501px) {
.tags-div {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: yes that works as well, although with some extra markup. Do you know the reason for buggy behavior in my code, since it works in FF, IE?